# Java plugin for Visual Studio Code cannot load Spring Boot classes when start debugging a multi-module Maven project

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code with Red Hat Java Plug-in and Debugger for Java plugin. I got a problem that:

1) If I work with a single module Maven project, everything is ok.

2) But if I open a multi-module Maven project, the debugger cannot start because of "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer"

3) The project can be built with Maven, and running the Jar is all right

I guess the problem is because of the classpath settings, however to my understanding, the .classpath file should be derived from the POM file, which should be correct, otherwise Maven would have not been able to build the project.

I did not manually modify the launch.json, and the plug-ins generated the settings for me.

Comment: Maven has nothing to do with `.classpath`. Your IDE should handle this...

Comment: Yes, I know, but I think the IDE(Visual Studio Code) should derive (part of) the classpath from the POM, therefore there may also be problems with the POM?

Comment: Just test building on plain command line....first to see if your issue is located in the pom or not ?

Comment: I have tried, and if I do not use anything from Spring Boot, it works. I guess the IDE cannot find the classes of the dependencies from POM

Comment: I have written. Test on plain command line which should work independent of the framework you are using also with Spring Boot..(The question is how you use it?)...The IDE should not be used for this..

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. It works when I use plain command line, both build and execution are ok.

Comment: No problem. If it now works it's fine...

Comment: I have a similar problem except that it is another class which is not found, see https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-spring-boot-dashboard/issues/52
I'm sharing it in case in can give ideas on what to investigate :s